# how to download or get attachment from other groups and folders in outlook rather than inbox

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, pop3

i want to download attachments from a particular mail id from a specific folder and group which is configured in outlook for office
i am getting this error

i have tried changing the string from INBOX to other folder,and attachment will be saved in a folder on  my local machine

```
Store store = session.getStore("pop3");
store.connect(userName, password);
Folder folderInbox = store.getFolder("payslip");
folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
Message[] arrayMessages = folderInbox.getMessages();
```

i am getting the following error

```
Could not connect to the message store
javax.mail.FolderNotFoundException: folder is not INBOX
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Folder.open(POP3Folder.java:192)
    at com.jcp.automation.EmailAttachmentReceiver.downloadEmailAttachments(EmailAttachmentReceiver.java:68)
    at com.jcp.automation.EmailAttachmentReceiver.main(EmailAttachmentReceiver.java:150)
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.jcp.automation.EmailAttachmentReceiver).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Comment: Use imap instead of pop3?

Comment: @MauricePerry still not able to access groups in outlook

Comment: I'm not surprised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have used imap instead of pop3 here is the code

```
          properties.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    properties.setProperty("mail.imaps.port", "993");
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

    try {

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);

         javax.mail.Store store = session.getStore("imaps");


        store.connect("outlook.office365.com", "xyz", "xyz");
        Folder folderInbox = store.getFolder("james");
        folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
```